# How to define abstract fromArray method for enums in Php?

Tags: php, enums, code-duplication

I have following piece of code in several enums:

```
public static function fromArray(array $array): array
{
    return array_map(
        fn ($element) => self::from($element),
        $array
    );
}
```

Is there a way to be smarter about this and avoid code duplication?

As enums aren't extendable, I was thinking about approach with traits, but the issue is that trait would be dependent on the enum.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use an interface to define the dependency, implement it with the trait.

Comment: What did you mean trait would be dependent on the enum?

Comment: @shingo trait would need to look have this same function with `self::` replaced with something, and that something would be the enum itself, but then it's dependent on it and can't be used in other enums.

Comment: @shingo, ok, looks like I've overlooked something. The thing works if I just define the trait and copy paste the entire function inside trait. I find it a bit weird that trait doesn't get confused when I call `self::from` from inside trait, but I guess that's just me. Tnx!

Comment: a little bit about your confusion with traits: Traits in PHP are essentially a way to reuse code among different classes. When you use a trait in a class, the methods of the trait are inserted into that class as if they were written inside the class itself. This means that when you call self::from within the trait, self refers to the class that uses the trait, not the trait itself. These can also be used inside traits: parent::, self::, and $this, as well as abstract methods and even other traits.

Comment: Thanks! I'd upvote probably all the comments but seems like I haven't enough rep.